# Agrupación en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Intento realizar una consulta que solo me muestre una vez el dato por el cual se esta agrupando tengo algo de este estilo.

```
SELECT SEXO, COLOR, COUNT(*) FROM DATOS
GROUP BY SEXO, COLOR
```

Lo cual me genera una tabla de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento visualizar algo de este estilo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intenté con **GROUP BY CUBE**

Comment: Pienso que deberías intentar con la función **GROUP BY ROLLUP**. Aquí te dejo un link para que le chequees un ejemplo. [Diferencia entre ROLLUP y CUBE](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/163572/)

Comment: Podrias explicar porque necesitas que un query devuelva algo que no es logico para una base de datos? si esto es para solucionar un problema de vista, lo tiene que solucionar la vista...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT SEXO=CASE WHEN Fila>1 THEN '' ELSE SEXO END, 
COLOR, 
CANTIDAD
FROM(
SELECT SEXO, 
COLOR, 
COUNT(*) AS Cantidad,
Fila= ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Sexo ORDER BY Color) 
FROM DATOS
GROUP BY SEXO, COLOR)Subconsulta
```

Comment: Excelente!! Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda @BytesMan

Comment: Un gusto ayudar, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Esta es otra opción que se puede utilizar:

```
SELECT
    Sexo = IIF(ISNULL(LAG(Sexo) OVER (ORDER BY Sexo), '') <> Sexo, Sexo, ''),
    Color,
    COUNT(1)
FROM Datos d
GROUP BY    Sexo,
            Color
```